# Jquery - fadeIn() and fadeOut() in PNG image. Border Solid (black) in IE8...?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, png

I am running a fadeIn() and fadeOut() in a block of div where there is a PNG image, with semi-transparent funds (with shadow).

See in http://jsfiddle.net/k3KUj/8/embedded/

In IE 8, it appears the hard edges when you run the fadeIn() and fadeOut(), but soon disappears. In Firefox, it's OK.

Logical to apply a background color in PNG (for example, with the link above, the background color should be light gray), it works.

But do not want to put a background color in PNG. I'm trying to get black borders do not appear in IE 8, even if you have a PNG image transparency.

Looking at the response in the [forum](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=590295), tried:

> -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)" ; /* IE8 */
>
>   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);   /* IE6 & 7 */
>   zoom: 1;

and see in [jquery IE Fadein and Fadeout Opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284163/jquery-ie-fadein-and-fadeout-opacity)

> $('#bloc').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=40)');

and see in [fadeIn / fadeOut jquery problem with IE7/8 & png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615597/fadein-fadeout-jquery-problem-with-ie7-8-png)

> $("#bloc").css('filter', 'none');

But, doesn't work. Any new idea, without applying any color in the image background transparent?

Thanks, Vinicius.

Comment: For information about why IE works so poorly with jQuery's fading when you have (semi-)transparent images, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156985/jquery-cycle-ie7-transparent-png-problem

Answer (score 1):

Define a solid background color to your image:

```
    .container img {
         background-color: white;
    }
```

Define the **background-image** css property of your image to its **src** attribute:

```
    $('.holder-thumbs li a img').each(function() {
         $(this).css('background-image', $(this).attr('src'));
    });
```

Advantage: you don't need to change your markup

Disadvantage: sometimes applying a solid background color is not an acceptable solution. It normally is for me.