# Opacity is not working on images in IE8

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-8, background-image, opacity

Opacity is not being inherited by the images in a DIV with opacity in IE8 and I'm not sure why. One is an image via HTML, and the other images are set as a background in CSS (to achieve a roll over effect).  It works properly in IE7, IE9, Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

My code is in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/46AKc/5/

If I apply

```
opacity: .75; /* Standards Compliant Browsers */
filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* IE 7 and Earlier */
    /* Next 2 lines IE8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75);
```

to **#hover-prod1**, the rollover's opacity changes but it does not seamlessly blend into **.slide-out** the way it does in other browsers, so I don't think that is the right solution.

I have tried the solutions in the following posts with no luck:
[Opacity CSS not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948176/opacity-css-not-working-in-ie8)
[Opacity in IE8 works on <p> but not on <a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452868/opacity-in-ie8-works-on-p-but-not-on-a?lq=1)
[Opacity not working on img in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377603/opacity-not-working-on-img-in-ie8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, change these two lines:

.slide-out a:hover{color:#F36F21;}

.hover-products{position: relative; width:338px; margin:20px 0 50px 15px; height: 90px;}

to this:

.slide-out a:hover{color:#F36F21;  position: relative;}

.hover-products{width:338px; margin:20px 0 50px 15px; height: 90px;}

Answer (score 0):

That's because

```
.hover-products{
   position:relative;
}
```

Just remove it.

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/46AKc/7/