# jQuery IE Cleartype glitch on fadeout!

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, fadeout

Please do not point me to more articles about this issue I think I've read them all...
I have a div that has some text in it and I just wanted to fade it out in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dHeaderMessage').fadeOut(12000, function() { 
    });  
});
```

This fades out correctly but the text inside of this div looks awful when the page first loads up (IE8).  So I googled it and it mentioned its some ClearType font issue with IE.
The workaround was to remove a "filter" in javascript like so:

`document.getElementById('dHeaderMessage').style.removeAttribute("filter");`

But this did not seem to make any change...so I tried doing it right within the jQuery:

```
$('#dHeaderMain').fadeOut(12000, function() { 
        this.style.removeAttribute("filter");
    });
```

Still the same issue the text looks blurry...
How can I solve this?

Comment: I have one: **don't** use a clearType font.

Comment: I've experienced a ton of JQuery fade issues acroos IE versions. I ended up just disabling the fade in IE through conditional JQuery code in some instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

`$('#dHeaderMessage').delay(20000).fadeOut('slow');`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I found it easy to fix. If you can, give the div a background color. That fixed it for me.